# What code would you put before/after your R session?

Tags: r

R allows us to put code to run in the beginning/end of a session.

What codes would you suggest putting there?

I know of three interesting examples (although I don't have "how to do them" under my fingers here):

1. Saving the [session history](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/savehistory.html) when closing R.
2. Running a fortune() at the beginning of an R session.
3. I was thinking of having an automated saving of the workspace.  But I didn't set on solving the issue of managing space (so there would always be X amount of space used for that backup)

Any more ideas? (or how you implement the above ideas)

p.s: I am not sure if to put this here or on stackoverflow.  But I feel the people here are the right ones to ask.

Comment: Probably better suited to stackoverflow since it has no particular data analysis relevance.

Comment: This question is proposed to be closed. See this meta thread: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213/list-of-candidate-questions-to-be-closed

Comment: I wish we could move a question to Stack Overflow the way you can move a question from Super User...

Comment: I moved it manually to stackoverflow. JD - I agree with you.

Comment: Following on from http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252/should-we-allow-more-computing-questions I've reopened this question.

Answer (score 5):

Some information about how to implement this is provided at `help(.First)` and `help(.Last)`.

Answer (score 2):

On open, I set R options, load environment variables (eg. global variables, API keys) and open database connections, and then close those connections when exiting. With some of these things, I prefer to do them onLoad of my packages rather than per session.

Regarding how to save your session, use the save command.